# Do homosexuals avoid zina in the same way?

Tags: sin, homosexuality, zina

If someone is born homosexual, with completely no interest in those of the same sex, how would the laws/guidelines on approaching zina affect them?

For example, would it be haraam for a homosexual woman to to look at an unveiled woman? Or would it be considered approaching zina if a homosexual man were to hold the hand of another man?

How does this work in reversal? For example, if a heterosexual man were to shake hands with a homosexual man (feeling no arousal), but he's aware that the man is homosexual, would he be sinning?

Comment: There is no clear evidence to whether someone can be born homosexual, or whether childhood plays a predominant role. Allah knows best.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you may look at the act in a more significant manner. Meaning... looking at anyone, regardless of the sex or sexual preference, is not haraam. A man looking at a man, a woman looking at a man, a boy looking at a man ... these acts of looking are not haraam in any way.

It is the MANNER in which one looks, that can become haraam. So, we can conclude, through the beautiful Guidance of Allah Most Mysterious, that intention is a key factor in this act of "looking". And it is haraam even if the transgresor is the only one who knows of the wrong intention of his / her looking.

As for holding of hands, it is clear that physical contact between any two people, is reserved for those who have the right, privilege or relation to do so. As also, is the Guidance of our Most Divine Allah, Most Wise. Again, this can be logically accepted as a most worthy Guide. As it is physical contact which leads to intimacy. And intimacy can evolve into seductive thoughts. Which can, in turn, transfer to sexual intentions and acts.

So, although the holding of hands is not "wrong" at all, it is an act of intimacy that needs to be respected in order to avoid unclean thoughts. And rather than place risk upon those less acquainted, rather than invoke intimate thoughts by onlookers who may continue into unclean intentions, rather than risk inviting the other person to have unclean thoughts (for which he will be answerable), it is the wisest (note I say wisest and not most understandable) choice to avoid holding hands....can you see where this goes? It is best to refrain from holding hands unless it is with a those that are permitted by Allah Most Insightful.

Perhaps this will help you draw your own clear, balanced and wise decision. I can only add and remind, that Allah All Knowing, declared that the greatest Gift he bestows upon man is the intelligence, Alghamdu Lilaah. It is up to us, to expand our thinking to what is the wisest, and not what makes the easiest sense.

> Say to believing women that they should lower their gaze and remain
> chaste and not to reveal their adornments save what is normally
> apparent thereof, and they should fold their shawls over their bosoms.
> They can only reveal their adornments to their husbands or their
> fathers or the husbands fathers, or their sons or their husbands sons
> or their brothers or their brothers sons or their sisters sons or
> maidservants or those whom their right hand possess or their make
> attendance or their male attendants who have no sexual desire or
> children who still have no carnal knowledge of women.
>
> Al Quraan - LIGHT 24:31 -

I answer the question with absolute respect and in bowing humility. As I acknowledge there is no complete answer. As in order to remain filled with desire for true enlightenment and driven for the Pleasure of Allah All Powerful, we must respond when someone seeks a positive influence. I ask apology for any offence my comment may draw from the most respected Umah.

Answer (score 0):

The question itself is irrelevant. Allah wouldn't prescribe something as haraam if it was a natural part of someone's physical makeup. For e.g., all people are made to have a sexual urge  as a part of the process of procreation and Allah The Creator has prescribed marriage as the acceptable way to indulge in that urge. He only makes it haraam to have sex outside of a marriage, He hasn't made sex haraam at all times. Since homosexuality is not in that category and has been made haraam at all times, the only conclusion we can draw as Muslims is that homosexuality is not a natural state i.e. Allah did not make anyone homosexual at birth. No one is ever born a homosexual and therefore the question is based on a false premise.

Edit: "*On no soul doth Allah Place a burden greater than it can bear*. It gets every good that it earns, and it suffers every ill that it earns. (Pray:) "Our Lord! Condemn us not if we forget or fall into error; our Lord! Lay not on us a burden Like that which Thou didst lay on those before us; Our Lord! Lay not on us a burden greater than we have strength to bear. Blot out our sins, and grant us forgiveness. Have mercy on us. Thou art our Protector; Help us against those who stand against faith." Quran Ch.2:V.286 http://quran.com/2/286

I think that is pretty strong evidence. The strength of sexual urge is not something that can be withstood by man, given in the context of the relation between the genders and marriage in An-Nisa. "Allah doth wish to lighten your (difficulties): For man was created Weak (in flesh)." Quran Ch.4:V.28 http://quran.com/4/28. Everyone has been affected by that urge at one time or the other,no matter how much willpower they have. That is by design otherwise the species would die out. Hence the device of marriage to satisfy that need lawfully, among other advantages of marriage.

Riba is not a physical temptation i.e. it is not a built in or born with temptation like sex,so that is a wrong category comparison. A thing is not forbidden because we have urges for it. Anything that is forbidden in Islam has a reason it is forbidden. Riba because it is an unlawful gain. Smoking because it harms your health and so on.

A cigarette addiction can be overcome because no one believes it to be part of who we are. On the other hand,if someone believes that being gay is part of who they are when they are born and they have no choice in the matter, then they don't see it as a problem.

As to tempting them into what is haraam, again the approach depends on what you believe to be haraam or not. For a gay person, if s/he believes they are born with it and god made them like that, then they won't accept it as haraam. therefore the clamour for legalising gay marriage.

Comment: It could be a test in that they have an urge for something haraam. In a sense, all of us have urges for forbidden things, such as riba -- that is why it is forbidden. I think the question stands even if they were not born that way. Even if they trained themselves to be that way, like how a smoker makes himself addicted to cigarettes, they still have the urges and we should not tempt them further into what is haraam.

Comment: "Allah wouldn't prescribe something as haraam if it was a natural part of someone's physical makeup" is a pretty bold claim.  Do you have evidence to back it up?